# How do I disable the "Flood attempts IP blocking" functionality?

Tags: 7, users

Drupal blocks the IP used to access the site, when a user tries to log in many times.

How can I disable this functionality?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you can do is adding the following code in the settings.php file.

```
$conf['user_failed_login_ip_limit'] = PHP_INT_MAX;
```

In this way, the IP will not blocked.

[user_login_authenticate_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_authenticate_validate/7) contains the following code.

```
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['name']) && !empty($password)) {
    // Do not allow any login from the current user's IP if the limit has been
    // reached. Default is 50 failed attempts allowed in one hour. This is
    // independent of the per-user limit to catch attempts from one IP to log
    // in to many different user accounts.  We have a reasonably high limit
    // since there may be only one apparent IP for all users at an institution.
    if (!flood_is_allowed('failed_login_attempt_ip', variable_get('user_failed_login_ip_limit', 50), variable_get('user_failed_login_ip_window', 3600))) {
      $form_state['flood_control_triggered'] = 'ip';
      return;
    }
    $account = db_query("SELECT * FROM {users} WHERE name = :name AND status = 1", array(':name' => $form_state['values']['name']))->fetchObject();
    if ($account) {
      if (variable_get('user_failed_login_identifier_uid_only', FALSE)) {
        // Register flood events based on the uid only, so they apply for any
        // IP address. This is the most secure option.
        $identifier = $account->uid;
      }
      else {
        // The default identifier is a combination of uid and IP address. This
        // is less secure but more resistant to denial-of-service attacks that
        // could lock out all users with public user names.
        $identifier = $account->uid . '-' . ip_address();
      }
      $form_state['flood_control_user_identifier'] = $identifier;

      // Don't allow login if the limit for this user has been reached.
      // Default is to allow 5 failed attempts every 6 hours.
      if (!flood_is_allowed('failed_login_attempt_user', variable_get('user_failed_login_user_limit', 5), variable_get('user_failed_login_user_window', 21600), $identifier)) {
        $form_state['flood_control_triggered'] = 'user';
        return;
      }
    }
    // We are not limited by flood control, so try to authenticate.
    // Set $form_state['uid'] as a flag for user_login_final_validate().
    $form_state['uid'] = user_authenticate($form_state['values']['name'], $password);
  }
```

The limits are actually two: one for the case Drupal always has an IP, and one for when Drupal has also a user ID. The latter is for the case the user enters a username for an existing account; in that case, Drupal register the user ID, and the IP.
If you want to avoid also that case, then you need to add also this line to the setting.php file.

```
$conf['user_failed_login_user_limit'] = PHP_INT_MAX;
$conf['user_failed_login_user_window'] = 5;
```

Comment: Hi Kiamlaluno, so it means i ONLY NEED to add these 2 lines in the `settings.php`? Is `PHP_INT_MAX` the infinite limit? Can i also set that infinite limit (PHP_INT_MAX) to `user_failed_login_user_window` also? Because it is set as `5` there.

Comment: `PHP_INT_MAX` is the maximum value PHP can assign to an integer. I set the other value to 5 because that is the number of seconds for which the limit is valid. If you set user_failed_login_user_limit to 10, and user_failed_login_user_window to 5, it means 10 login attempts are allowed in 5 seconds. Just change the settings.php file, and the IPs/users are not blocked anymore.

Comment: Sorry for my understandability but i'm still not so cleared yet. I searched and found that [PHP_INT_MAX] is 2 Billions. Ok then, does it means we will allow upto 2 Billions attempts between 5 Sec now? Is it already ready for both of IP & Username also?

Comment: My final concern is to TOTALLY DISABLE the IP and/or USERNAME attempt Blocking. [NO LIMITATIONS anymore to set] Are these only 2 lines solve it already?

Comment: For a 64-bit machine, `PHP_INT_MAX` is 9223372036854775807; for a 32-bit machine its value is 2147483647. You are correct; that is the number of attempts in 5 seconds. If the number of attempts are lower than that, the IP/user is not blocked.

Comment: Already covers for both IPs/Users? Okie thanksss so much (for both of Answer and Explanations) :D

Comment: To totally disable it, you need to periodically purge the content of a database table, and that cannot be done from the settings.php file.

Comment: Hmmm.. Why do i need it please? Because the `limitations` will never be occurring anymore by using those 2 Setting Variables. Right? IF SO IT STILL NEED, can i finally Disable/Comment-out some Code Lines inside the Function?

Comment: Uhmmm... Hacking core is a bad practice. Adding those lines avoids the users are blocked. Nobody is going to hit that limit, especially for 64-bit machines.

Answer (score 6):

In **Drupal 8**, you can change the flood settings in the config file `user.flood.yml`.

```
uid_only: false
ip_limit: 50
ip_window: 3600
user_limit: 5
user_window: 21600
_core:
  default_config_hash: UYfMzeP1S8jKaaaavxf7nQNe8DsNS-3bc2WSNNXBQWs
```

This means that per IP and per user, there is a limit:

- Per 3600 seconds (1 hour), 50 attempts per IP address are allowed
- Per 21600 seconds (6 hours), 5 attempts per user account are allowed (quite few)

You might change and import the settings (i set it to 100 attempts per 5 minutes):

```
uid_only: false
ip_limit: 100
ip_window: 300
user_limit: 100
user_window: 300
_core:
  default_config_hash: UYfMzeP1S8jKaaaavxf7nQNe8DsNS-3bc2WSNNXBQWs
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in settings.php, or similar, instead of modifying core/modules/user/config/install/user.flood.yml?

Comment: @dhruveonmars you can override every setting in your settings.php. It would be something like `$config['user.flood']['user_limit'] = 100;`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 5):

The [Flood Control](https://drupal.org/project/flood_control) module will handle this elegantly.