# How can I limit the password reset attempts?

Tags: users

I have Google Recaptcha, but some users try to recovery password too often. I didn't find any solution for this problem. I want to make 5 attempts limit for this.

Comment: Is this Drupal 7 or Drupal 8? Please add the appropriate tag - 7 or 8.

Comment: How to do this in Drupal 9 without adding a module?

Comment: Use Drush. See: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294599/how-do-i-change-the-limit-of-user-accounts-gets-blocked-or-suspended

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Flood Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_control) module for it.

> Flood Control provides an administration interface for hidden flood
> control variables, like the login attempt limiters and any future
> hidden variables.

Comment: This module has no affect on password reset form, just on login page

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Drupal 7 does not have such option at the moment but there is a patch and also you can create your own module to fix this.

1. Patch https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3074666
   1.1) After applying of the patch add to the end of the file /sites/default/settings.php line that defines number of attempts:

```php
$conf['user_pass_reset_user_limit'] = 3;
```

2. Create your own module
   2.1) Prepare files for your module xandeadx.ru/blog/drupal/256
   2.2) Modify password reset form, code can be taken from here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1681832

```php
// xyz - your module name
function xyz_user_pass_form_validate($form, $form_state){
  // 3 - stands for number of password reset limit made during 86400 seconds
  if(!flood_is_allowed('request new password', 3, 86400, $form_state['values']['name'])){
    form_set_error('name', 'Reset password limit exceeded.  Please contact technical support for further assistance.');
  flood_register_event('request new password', 86400, $form_state['values']['name']);
  } else {
    flood_register_event('request new password', 86400, $form_state['values']['name']);
  }
}

hook_form_user_pass_alter($form){
  array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'xyz_user_pass_form_validate');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!